# Java/Maven and Scala/sbt projects share immutable thing

Tags: java, scala, maven

Project 1: a Java/Maven project

Project 2: a Scala/sbt project

Thing: generally, an immutable object instantiated in from 3rd party Java library.  For example, `ThingBuilder.foo("bar").build()`

Question: How can I define Thing in only one place, and have it used both in Project 1 and 2?  (So the parameters in ThingBuilder are guaranteed to be the same in both projects.)

Comment: Just to be clear. In your example there are two different executables from the two projects running in two different JVM's. You're not simply trying to reuse a class defined in one language in the other language. Right?

Comment: Exactly.  Perhaps the best way is to make Project 3, having Project 3 jar as a dependency in both, with some wrapper object to produce Thing.  I don't really know!  And would I do it in Java or Scala :)

Comment: Er no, what I want to know is if you're trying to share runtime state between two running executables, one of which has created the `Thing` object with a certain state and the other did not but wants to use it in that state. Or if you just want to be able to define `Thing` with a java class in the java project but create it as an object in your scala project where you would give it state and not share that object with the java/maven project.

Comment: The second goal: define it in a single place, instantiate it in both projects, but the instantiated objects are not shared/an instantiated object is not shared.  The two executables communicate through a messaging system, so it's important they work with the same definition of Thing, but they don't share an instance of it directly.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to create a library wrapping the creation of the immutable object, and have it's creation driven by a shared config file.

[lightbend's config](https://github.com/lightbend/config) is useful for this because it's implemented in Java, despite being a lightbend project.